# Download files from firebase storage and display it whenever required even when app is offline

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-storage

I am developing an android app where students upload notes in pdf format and others download them. I am unable to figure out how to manage downloaded notes so I can show them when the app is offline, Do I need to maintain a Database of Downloaded files for it? How to avoid downloading notes again when required

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit abstract. Still,

Of course downloading the same thing again again is an overhead on the network. As I see, your issue is with how to fetch the data to the viewers.

This might depend on what your 'note' type is and also its size. Also what your application is. (Webapp, Mobileapp)

Assuming that this is a mobile app and the notes are in the format of JPEG files;
You application can download it save it in the device storage. When fetching the downloaded information to the viewer, you can either fetch image by image from the storage location. Or else, just leave that to the end users themselves to decide a suitable app for that.(If your notes are in a generic format which is supported by explorer applications. No need to write an app to open PDFs.)
If your note uploaders have uploaded any revisions for the same file to your server, you can check for a hash value for your downloaded file and the server's available latest file. If the hash is of any different, then re-download. But if the revisions are maintained in the server with a good versioning mechanism, your mobile app can send the current version to the server, then the server will decide if a re-download is needed or not.

Comment: I re-edited question to give platform-specific details. But the main puzzle was how to maintain track notes of downloaded notes. Since manually sorting and searching them whenever an app is launched is a burdensome task